# A and B are similar if and only if $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations (on the same finite dimensional vector space) such that $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$.  Is it true that $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if rank($A$)=rank($B$)?

As far as I can tell, it is true.  What I have for the forward direction is this:

$A=C^{-1}BC$

$CA=BC$

And by a theorem, we can say, rank($CA$)=rank($BC$).  Further, by the same theorem, we can say, rank($A$)=rank($B$) because $C$ is invertible.

I'm stuck on the reverse direction though.  I can put an invertible $C$ in there, but past that, I don't think I can make the assumption that $CA=BC$.

Thanks.

Comment: It is true, since $A^2=A$ means that $A$ is diagonalizable and that the eigenvalues are all $1$ and $0$ and the rank is equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001157/106213

Comment: Mutliplying by an invertible matrix never alters rank and by definition of similarity $C$ needs to be invertible.