# Is there an isomorphism between projections?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ a finite dimension vector space and let $T$ be a linear operator such that $T^2 = T$. Suppose there's another linear operator $R$ such that $R^2 = R$. Is there an isomorphism $\rho$ such that $R= \rho^{-1} \circ T \circ \rho$ ?

I was thinking the answer is yes, due to the fact that $T$ and $R$ are diagonalizable, and so, I can find $\beta \text{ and } \beta^{\prime}$ basis of $V$ such that $A = [T]_{\beta}$ and $B=[R]_{\beta^{\prime}}$. Then I can find a matrix $Q$ such that $Q$ is a matrix change coordinates from $\beta$ to $\beta^{\prime}$, and then 
$$B = Q^{-1}AQ$$

I don't know if my reasoning is correct and, regardless of being right or wrong, I'm wondering if there's another proof, a more formal proof, for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true is general as consider two transformation $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

They are similar if and only if they have same rank!!

Proof: [Two idempotent matrices are similar iff they have the same rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001157/two-idempotent-matrices-are-similar-iff-they-have-the-same-rank)

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! I was wondering if it's sufficient to prove that $tr(A) \neq tr(B)$, instead of proving that $rank(A) \neq rank(B)$?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.  For a counterexample, look at the matrices

$T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag 1$

and

$R = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

Both

$R^2 = R, \; T^2 = T \tag 3$

hold, but $R$ and $T$ are not similar; their characteristic polynomials are different; we have

$p_T(x) = (x - 1)x^2 = x^3 - x^2, \tag 4$

but

$p_R(x) = x(x - 1)^2 = x^3 - 2x^2 + x. \tag t$

Comment: We don't even need to find the characteristic polynomial as similar matrices have same rank and same trace!

Comment: @StammeringMathematician:  one way or another . . . 

Comment: This is a offtopic question!! "Music is my wife,Mathematics is my mistress; can't leave that girl alone!" Robert where did you find that quote. Did you make it yourself. I am avid football fan and yesterday I saw a similar quote by a person on reddit "Arsenal is my wife, Barcelona is my mistress" What is the source? P.S. Sorry for my English. It is not my first language.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician:  I made it up!  But certainly the wife-mistress duality is well-known!  Cheers!